# How to split a string with space into two lines in python

Tags: python

I am trying to split github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0 into name and version

I tried like this but it only split into 2.
output i am getting is
[{'name': 'pmezard', 'version': 'v1.0.0\n'}]

Expected output
[{'name': 'go-difflib', 'version': 'v1.0.0'}]

```
path = foldername + "/example.txt"    
print(path)    
file = open(path)    
Lines = file.readlines()    
List = []    
for line in Lines:    
    depends = {}
    if (len(line.split(" ")) > 1):    
        depends["name"] = line.split(" ")[1]    
        depends["version"] = line.split(" ")[1]    
        List.append(depends)
```

Comment: A regex might be a solution depending on the use (just for your username or for more general use?).

Comment: The only issue I found in your code was that name should get:
line.split(" ")[0]

Comment: you can use string.strip() to remove any starting and ending whitespace

Comment: `res = line.split(" ")` then
`res = {"name" : line[0].split('/')[-1].strip(), "version" : line[1].strip()}` but a regex would be a better idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering all string of format `github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0`

```py
path = foldername + "/example.txt"
print(path)
file = open(path)
Lines = file.readlines()
file.close()  # close file
List = []    
for line in Lines:
    try:
        link, version = line.split(" ")
    except ValueError:
        continue
    name = link.split("/")[-1]
    List.append({"name": name, "version": version})
```

For complex pattern, regex may be helpful

Comment: It looks working but i am still getting version as 'version': 'v1.0.0\n'

Comment: you can remove whitespaces, `version.strip()`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `os.path` module.

```
import os
name, version = os.path.basename(line).split(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
text = 'github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0'
splitted_text = text.split(' ')
name = splitted_text[0].split('/')[-1]
version = splitted_text[-1]
print(f'name: {name}, version: {version}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex for this:

```
import re

s = 'github.com/pmezard/go-difflib v1.0.0'

l = re.search('([^\/]+$)', s).group().split(' ')

# Out: 
# ['go-difflib', 'v1.0.0']
```